# databinding error : databinding does not exist

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

i tried listview app to use mvvm pattern.

but i have errors in android studio.

i don't know why this project doesn't work.

[structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCf7F.png)

error:

1. Error:(18, 49) error: package com.example.jhseo.flight_mvvm.databinding does not exist
2. Error:(30, 13) error: cannot find symbol class FlightActivityBinding
3. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

   > java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
   >   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. viewModel is missing it
   >   file:E:\workspace_mobile\test\Flight-Mvvm\app\src\main\res\layout\flight_item.xml
   >   loc:15:27 - 15:35
   >   ****\ data binding error ****

> FlightActivity

```
public class FlightActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FlightViewModel.DataListener{
private FlightActivityBinding binding;
private FlightViewModel flightViewModel;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.flight_activity);
flightViewModel = new FlightViewModel(this, this);
binding.setViewModel(flightViewModel);

setupListVIew(binding.flightListView);

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onListChanged(ArrayList<Flight> flights) {
FlightListAdapter adapter =(FlightListAdapter) binding.flightListView.getAdapter();
adapter.setFlights(flights);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void setupListVIew(ListView flightListView) {
FlightListAdapter adapter = new FlightListAdapter(this);
flightListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}        
}
```

> FlightViewModel

```
public class FlightViewModel {

FlightFactory flightFactory;
...
public ObservableArrayList<Flight> flightList;

private Context context;
private DataListener dataListener;
private Realm realm;

public FlightViewModel(Context context, DataListener dataListener) {
this.context = context;
this.dataListener = dataListener;
init();
loadData();
}

public void setDataListener(DataListener dataListener) { this.dataListener = dataListener; }

...

public void searchByConditionInListAndSet() {
RealmQuery<Flight> query = realm.where(Flight.class);

if (!"".equals(terminal.get())) {
query = query.equalTo("terminal", terminal.get());
}
flightList.addAll(query.findAll().subList(0, (int) query.count()));
if (dataListener != null) {
dataListener.onListChanged(flightList);
}
 ...
}
public interface DataListener {
void onListChanged(ArrayList<Flight> flights);
}
}
```

> ItemViewModel

```
public class ItemViewModel extends BaseObservable {
private Flight flight;
private Context context;

public ItemViewModel(Flight flight, Context context) {
this.flight = flight;
this.context = context;
}
...
public void onItemClick(View view) {
//TODO: Detail Page
 //context.startActivity();
}

public void setFlight(Flight flight) {
this.flight = flight;
notifyChange();
}
}
```

> flight_activity.xml
>
> flight_item.xml

```
<data>
        <variable
            name="itemModel"
            type="com.example.jhseo.flight_mvvm.viewModel.ItemViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="@{viewModel::onItemClick}">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@{itemModel.time}" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/flightStateTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@{itemModel.flightState}" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/destinationi"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/destinationTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@{itemModel.destination}" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/counterAndGatei"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/counterAndGateTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@{itemModel.counterAndGate}" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/origini"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/originTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@{itemModel.origin}" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/carouseli"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/carouselTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@{itemModel.carousel}" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/exitDoori"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/exitDoorTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@{itemModel.exitDoor}" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you got is pretty clear: there is no identifier `viewModel` defined within `flight_item.xml`.

Change

```
android:onClick="@{viewModel::onItemClick}"
```

to

```
android:onClick="@{itemModel::onItemClick}"
```

in `flight_item.xml` file.